# QRegExp - color word before ::

Tags: regex, qt

So, I am using `QSyntaxHiglihter` to create syntax highlight rules for my editor. I am using `QRegExp` for this purpose. Now, regular expressions is not my field, so anybody know how to create a rule for say,

```
std::cout
```

with std one color, and cout another? I tried with `QRegExp("\\b::\\b");`, but that only colors the colons. Thanks!

Figured it out: `\\b[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?=::)`

Answer (score 1):

You can not solve your problem without a basic understanding of regular expressions. The documentation of [QRegExp](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QRegExp.html#details) contains a brief introduction. If I were you I would read it and the [Syntax Highlighter Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/richtext-syntaxhighlighter.html). These two articles will help you find the answer to your questions.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was just soo tired last night. I have now read the documentation, and it should work with `\b[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?=::)`. However, it doesn't :)